# How to get real timestamp when getting coordinate from Geolocator in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, time, geolocation, mdm

I have a problem - we developing enterprise app and there we need to know the exact real time when getting coordinate from gps. The new and old API in WP8 provides Coordinate.Position.Timestamp on result but surprisingly it gives system time, not info from satellite (though it was possible for eg in Windows Mobile) . System time could be changed by user, so its not the solution for me.

So i see here 3 possible solutions:
 1)MS somehow rework they API so it can provide real Timestamp when getting from satellite (ok from wifi or cellular it could be null). Any thoughts on question why they removed real time? 
2)Get time from some web service - already made that, but there is a condition that solution must work also offline.
3)use one of the Mobile device management solutions like Intunes to set system time and block it from changing. Though all the research i've made - cant get exact answer from vendors, seems like this also impossible. Any thoughts on this?

Am i'm missing something in this trivial question? Thank you.

Comment: have you tried Geocoordinate.PositionSourceTimestamp?

Comment: PositionSourceTimestamp? There's no such property in native Geocoordinate. Are you sure u not misspelling or using another component?

Comment: [check this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thunbrynt/archive/2014/04/22/windows-phone-8-1-for-developers-geolocation-and-geofencing.aspx) your idea will get cleared

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot! But no way to achieve the goal until realease of 8.1 (June 24 ?)

Comment: yes.I will put this in answer,if its useful to you then please mark it as accepted.